# How do I forward a meeting request from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, exchange-activesync

I have synced my mail and calender to our company's MS Exchange 2003 server using Outlook Web Access(OWA). I have received a meeting request that I wish to forward to someone. How do I do this using the default mail app? (iOS 4.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

There is an app for that.  It is called "Forward My Meeting."

Comment: So a 1.99 app is the answer? I know the developer is just trying to make a living, but this seems a feature that even the simplest of mail apps can do with 1 click. Why is this not a feature of the current stock mail app? Needless to say, I have spent the 2 bucks and I am currently trying the app. I fear that in 2 weeks this will be a feature of ios 6 and I just wasted 2 bucks... :)